# How to use two key functions when sorting a MultiIndex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

In this call to `df.sort_index()` on a MultiIndex dataframe, how to use `func_2` for level `two`?

```
func_1 = lambda s: s.str.lower()
func_2 = lambda x: np.abs(x)
m_sorted = df_multi.sort_index(level=['one', 'two'], key=func_1)
```

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) says "*For MultiIndex inputs, the key is applied per level*", which is ambiguous.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)

# Create multiIndex
choice = lambda a, n: np.random.choice(a, n, replace=True)
df_multi = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': pd.Series(choice(['a', 'B', 'c'], 8)),
    'two': pd.Series(choice([1, -2, 3], 8)),
    'A': pd.Series(choice([2,6,9,7] ,8))
    })
df_multi = df_multi.set_index(['one', 'two'])

# Sort MultiIndex
func_1 = lambda s: s.str.lower()
func_2 = lambda x: np.abs(x)
m_sorted = df_multi.sort_index(level=['one'], key=func_1)
```

Comment: From the docs, you can't call multiple funcs. A single callable is required and passed to each level. A solution would be to create two separate arrays based on the callables, run a lexsort, and index the multiindex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) takes a unique function as `key` that would be used for all levels.

That said, you could use a wrapper function to map the desired sorting function per level name:

```
def sorter(level, default=lambda x: x):
    return {
      'one': lambda s: s.str.lower(),
      'two': np.abs,
    }.get(level.name, default)(level)

df_multi.sort_index(level=['one', 'two'], key=sorter)
```

*NB. in case of no match a default function is used that returns the level unchanged.*

Another option with [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) instead of `sort_index`:

```
# levels, functions in desired sorting order
sorters = [('one', lambda s: s.str.lower()), ('two', np.abs)]

out = df_multi.iloc[np.lexsort([f(df_multi.index.get_level_values(lvl))
                                for lvl, f in sorters[::-1]])]
```

*`lexsort` uses the major keys last, thus the `[::-1]`*

Output:

```
         A
one two   
a    1   6
    -2   2
     3   7
B    1   6
    -2   7
    -2   7
     3   2
     3   6
```